# How could the humans have rejected the program if they had no choice?

Tags: the-matrix

> "nearly 99.9% of all test subjects accepted the program, as long as they were given a choice"

How could the humans have rejected the program if they had no choice? Isn't that a paradox? You cannot reject something if you have no choice, otherwise you would have a choice.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, are you inferring from the above that people given no choice rejected the program? That sentence gives no evidence for that per my understanding.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot earlier in the same monologue Smith talks about failures of early versions of the Matrix where "entire crops were lost" which suggests everyone rejected the program. Oh wait, the  99% quote is from the second film, with the Architect speaking...

Comment: @Jontia If that's what the OP is referring to it would be better edited into the question to make sense else it seems like they are inferring extra meaning from the above sentence.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The decision to give people a choice to accept or reject the program really only makes sense if they were rejecting it when **not** given a choice, and doing so in larger numbers than when given a choice.

Comment: The current answers follow my initial interpretation of this question, but I'm starting to wonder if we are all mis-interpreting it. I'm starting to suspect the question may be about the *logic* of what the architect says about *the previous versions*: how can people attached to the previous versions **reject** the program if they have no choice?

Comment: It's like the body rejecting a transplanted heart. It's not a conscious decision.

Comment: No government gives people the choice to overthrow the government, yet history is replete with people making that choice anyway.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's important to note that the Matrix isn't actually that convincing a simulation of reality. It [glitches regularly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaWOFmMiXZ4), the physics is [weird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u31OjOPF-ZI), it requires periodic rebooting (including regular brain-wipes for the occupants) and is, for those that are aware that they're inside a simulation, [immediately apparent to be a fake](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/52771/20774). In short, people are prone to noticing that they're in a sim and keep trying to find ways to get out of it, initially on a subconscious level, but eventually by actively trying to subvert the Matrix and find ways out. As Smith says,

> ... The perfect world was a dream that your primitive cerebrum kept trying
>   to wake up from.

The problem, as defined by the Architect is that all the glitches in the Matrix eventually become so apparent to the subject that they eventually realise, on a conscious level, that they're in unreality and reject the system. They end up mad, dead, suicidal or actively trying to subvert the system and eventually tell more people that the system is fake which creates a cascade of problems.

The Oracle came up with a solution, namely the Choice (with a big c). If people are periodically polled on a subconscious level to see whether they're happy with their reality, ***even despite the fact that it's obviously a dud***, the vast majority will accept their reality. Conversely, a small number will choose otherwise and they can be safely ejected from the program and subsequently murdered.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what for "rejecting" would take without someone from Zion there to help out. There were a couple of Animatrix shorts which suggested a way out without outside help, but only the short conversation between Neo and Kid bridges these into the main films.

Comment: @Jontia - We see someone who couldn't (or wouldn't) leave in the Matrix Comic *[A Life Less Empty](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/Tiera)*. In short she suffers from depression and seems to be suicidal

Comment: And in the Matrix Comic Survivors, we learn that a mind that is shown (or discovers) the truth in adulthood simply dies in agony

Comment: I thought the matrix would in some way overwrite the brain, instead it seems more like a simple sort of virtual reality headset now.

Comment: @Herrsocke: It's a prison that the prisoners are mostly onboard and content with.

Comment: This answer involves a lot of speculation.  Which is entirely unnecessary, because (as explained in @Jontia's answer) the answer is given in the movie, in the exact same quote mentioned by the OP.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - Which part do you think is speculation?

Answer (score 30):

The entire quote from the scene, which is Neo's discussion with the Architect in The [Matrix Reloaded](https://genius.com/The-wachowskis-the-matrix-reloaded-architect-scene-annotated).

> ARCHITECT: Please. As I was saying, she stumbled upon a solution whereby nearly 99.9% of all test subjects accepted the program, as long as they were given a choice, even if they were only aware of the choice at a **near unconscious level**. While this answer functioned, it was obviously fundamentally flawed, thus creating the otherwise contradictory systemic anomaly, that if left unchecked might threaten the system itself. Ergo, those that refused the program, while a minority, if unchecked, would constitute an escalating probability of disaster.

Everyone is given choice, but most are not aware of it, and this is obviously flawed. Both logically and as a method of actual control, as the Architect points out. And leads to the rise of the anomaly "The One" who left unchecked would make the choice conscious by exposing the Matrix to everyone inside.

Comment: Neo was already doubtful, so his choice was quite apparent in Morpheus's offer.

Answer (score 20):

*Per my comment on the answer, I started to wonder if the question is actually more like: how can people attached to the previous versions **reject** the program if they have no choice? Adding this answer just in case, since the other answers don't address that interpretation.*

I suspect this just comes down to the use of language/terminology that has different meanings in different contexts.

Both Smith and The Architect use the word "accept" here. I think it's fair to read "reject" as the correct antonym, but I don't think they mean accept/reject in the sense that you might *choose* to accept/reject a gift or job offer.

I think they're using accept/reject in roughly the same way medical discourse describes whether a body accepts or rejects transplanted tissue.

Comment: As in "this world is too good to be true."

Comment: Yes, this was my understanding, as well. The host has rejected the implant, it’s just that in this case, the implant was a simulated reality instead of a kidney.